# Import data from a Google spreadsheet to another based on a cell value

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, importrange

I have 2 spreadsheets, I want to import data from one of them to another based on a cell value

Example: Sheet (A) has a column contains status (Review - Under processing - ...etc). I want to import just the data in the row that contains (Review) status.

Comment: If you are not using Excel, please don't tag with Excel. These are two very different apps, even if there is some functionality overlap.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("[URL FOR SHEET A]","[DATA RANGE]"),"WHERE colX CONTAINS '(Review)'",1)`

**Detail:**

This: `IMPORTRANGE("[URL FOR SHEET A]","[DATA RANGE]")` will link the two spreadsheets together. Note that you will have to grant the second spreadsheet permission to read from the first one when you first enter the function. You can play around with the datarange and use open ranges in case the data set is likely to grow.

Then: `QUERY([DATA],"[STATEMENT]",[HEADER])` will allow you to import only the stuff you want. [Read up](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) on the function to understand more, it is *very* useful. Only thing to note is that normally it will use the column letters (e.g. A, B, C) to refer to the columns, but since it's wrapped around the importrange and doesn't receive column letters, you have to use Col1, Col2, Col3 etc.